# delayed scroll down to a div id or some amount of pixel of the page

Tags: scroll

i call a .php file to my index page with get template_part which includes a few select boxes and a button to get the result page. Half of my page is full with header, slider and content so the file comes to bottom part of the page and button is simply at the bottom of the page. On click of the button it calls another .php file with the selected results. The button is at the end of the page and when clicked there is a delay of 1 second to call the other php file. (1 second delay is not my choice, it calls the file after 1 second and don't know why)

when the result comes it shows on the bottom of the page which is not visible unless the page is not scrolled manually.

What i need is to scroll the page automatically when the button is pressed but "href to div" or js scripts i found does not work because when the button is pressed those divs are not created because of the delay, after 1 sec the divs come visible.

how can i add a delay to scroll or what should i use.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution.

var $target = $('html,body');

$target.animate({scrollTop: $target.height()}, 50);,

code in the last called php file solved the question.

thanks